# any way to suppress warnings about "hardcoded strings" in layout files?

Tags: android, eclipse

**Is there a way I can suppress individual warnings about hardcoded strings in layout files?**

I often put placeholder text into TextViews so that I can see them in layout at design time. The downside of this is getting a ton of these warnings about hardcoded strings. But without them I wouldn't see the TextViews at all in the layout.

Comment: I get the principle of using `strings.xml`, but sometimes there are instances where you know you're only using the string once..

Comment: Good question. Seems like it would be nice to have some sort of escape character(s) to allow text as a placeholder, e.g. "<User name goes here>"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Eclipse, go to Window->Preferences->Android->Lint Error Checking.

Scroll down to and **select** Hardcoded Text (under Internationalization). On the Severity drop down box, select Ignore and click on Apply.

Comment: Similar for android studio as well. Preferences -> Android -> Lint ->Internationalization -> "Hardcoded Text" and "Text Internationalization". I toggle those on and off for toast's as well

Answer (score 36):

You can add the following to the text view element:

```
tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
```

Example:

```
    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a hardcoded text"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
```

Note there is a shortcut in Eclipse for adding this easily: just press CTRL + 1 and select the relevant option.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to do this for a whole layout, you will have to do it for each element.

Note that you must also add the `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools` attribute to the root element

Comment: This is what I want. I dont want to ignore all android lint warnings. They are useful anyway, but sometime they make me crazy because I know it and I don't need it :)

Comment: Note that you must also add the `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` attribute to the root element, otherwise you'll get errors like "Error parsing XML: unbound prefix".

Comment: Perfect solution, short, simple, and sweet.  Thanks!

Comment: to make it apply for the whole layout you gonna need to include it inside parent view.

Answer (score 31):

The other way is to use `tools:text` instead of `android:text`:

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="This is a hardcoded text" />
```

Note that you must also add the `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools` attribute to the root element

Comment: I find this better than `tools:ignore="HardcodedText"` because the preview is actually displaying it

Comment: Whaou, I didn't know about that, great find

Comment: I like this answer, but the linter complains about tools:text being hardcoded too, which is silly since it's just sample text that doesn't get compiled into the app... doesn't seem to be any way to turn it off...

Comment: @Andrew I'm not getting linter errors, perhaps due to a more recent version of the tools.

Comment: Another excellent answer!  This has the added benefit of making it clear that this is just temporary text for editing.

Comment: This method make the text disappeared from the design preview.

Comment: @InfiniteLoops put `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools` namespace in the root element

Answer (score 1):

Use `string.xml` file  to remove this warning....

You have to put your string in string.xml file and then give like `android:text="@string/mytext"`

And in `res-->value->string.xml add <string name="mytext">Your Text</string>`

http://tools.android.com/tips/lint

Comment: good link, never noticed the android tools site before.. looks like some useful info is there

Comment: thanks for suggestion but this adds more problems than it solves for me... I like to keep strings file relatively clean